Random slopes and intercepts in the metafor package: Model specification and output
I have two questions regarding a model specification in the metafor package (see correspondence: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2019-August/001650.html)
Question 1
Wolfgang wrote the following model specification in the e-mail thread:
res <- rma.mv(logOR, logOR.var, mods = ~ factor, 
   random = list(~ factor | meta, ~ 1 | trial), 
   struct="GEN", data=d)

Should seemingly add a multilevel structure with random intercepts for meta-analysis and trial level with trials nested within meta-analyses AND random slopes for the covariate within meta-analyses, i.e., that the effect may vary across meta-analyses.
I was wondering why one should not specify the model with: ~ 1 | id/row as the last element in the list of random-effects? That is the notation for instance in the lme4 package, and without it, I am uncertain where I identify the variance-component of the meta-analysis level in the model-output (see below)

Question 2:

Where do I identify the variance-component of the meta-analysis level?
Model output:
            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed    factor

sigma^2    

 

outer factor: id       (nlvls = X)

inner term:   ~ factor (nlvls = X)

 

              estim    sqrt  fixed  rho:  intr    c_SP

intrcpt        

factor     

Sigma2 is for the trial level row. Is intrcpt tau2 for meta-analyses level?
The model converges fine although complex when I examine Profile Likelihood Plots with profile(), and there are no indications of overparameterization.
Thanks in advance
FYI: A reply was made here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2024-November/005477.html
